# Regular expression for integers in java

Tags: java, regex

In my project  i want  to search an employee  id (integer)  within set of Data.
If user  enter  234 as  partial   data  then   i want  to  fetch all employee id  staring from 234. Currently  i  am  converting  int to  String and  then use   String`s  contains  method.
I want  to know is there any  better  approach for  this..

code

```
   String.valueof(employee.getEmployeeId()).contains(EnterNumber) ;
```

P.S.
I find  writting  regular  expression is very difficult,good  reference  to regEx would be  great. Thanks in  Advance

Comment: Where/how do you fetch employee data from? is it possible to give this criteria while fetching the data?

Comment: When you say "staring [sic] from 234", do you mean an integer value >= 234, or strings starting with the digits 234? If it's a matter of the former, I'd suggest using `Integer.parseInt()` and then `>= 234`. No need for regex.

Comment: why would any regex be better than doing a contains (or better yet, startsWith()) using string? If numbers `23456`, `234`, `234500054` all need to match it sounds like string comparison to me. Regex doesn't bring in any benefit.

Answer (score 0):

As you said starts with, this would work:

`'^(234).*'`

or

`'^'+input+'.*'`

Comment: it will search only at start of string not in complete string.

Answer (score 0):

If `Id` is a *number* (say `234789920252`), you can use regex like

```
  ^234\d*$
```

or

```
  String pattern = "^" + EnterNumber + "\\d*$";
```

If your task is to find out IDs that *start* with "234" you'd rather use `startWith`, not `contains`:

```
   String.valueof(employee.getEmployeeId()).startsWith(EnterNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a numeric solution following this formula:

```
trunc(n / 10^(trunc(log(n, 10)) - trunc(log(m, 10)))) == m
```

where `n` is the number you are testing, and `m` is the target numeric prefix to match. In your example, `m = 234`.

- `trunc(log(n, 10))` is the number of digits - 1 in `n`
- `trunc(log(m, 10))` is the number of digits - 1 in `m`
- if you divide `n` by `10^(trunc(log(n, 10)) - trunc(log(m, 10)))` and truncate it, the result is equal to `m` if `n` starts with `m`

An implementation in R for a proof of concept:

```
starts <- function(n, m) {
    trunc(n / 10^(trunc(log(n, 10)) - trunc(log(m, 10)))) == m
}
> starts(234, 234)
[1] TRUE
> starts(2345, 234)
[1] TRUE
> starts(23, 234)
[1] FALSE
> starts(123, 234)
[1] FALSE
> starts(1, 234)
[1] FALSE
> starts(9898, 234)
[1] FALSE
```

But is this better than converting to String and using regex to match? That, I don't know...

Comment: Database ID could be very long (up to int128 which corresponds to BCD Number(38)); that's why it's better to work with string representation of IDs